# Column Not Allowed SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

[Error Code Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNSUs.jpg) (ShipDate is now the error)

For my school project we are to create a product database where the customer places an order etc. I've compared my code to classmates and it's the essentially the same except I have less columns. This section of the code inserts the user input into the Orders Table.

The 2nd to last Column, OrderStatus, is where the * appears in the console. I apologize ahead of time if it looks messy, for some reason the format in the Body doesn't carry over to publish posts.

CODE:

```
INSERT INTO Orders
     VALUES (OrderNum,
             OrderDate,
             CustID,
             PNum,
             UnitPrice,
             QtyOrder,
             TotalCost,
             ShipDate,
             QtyShipped,
             OrderStatus,
             NULL);

SELECT MaxNum,
       SYSDATE,
       &vCustID,
       '&vPNum',
       UnitPrice,
       &vQty,
       TotalCost,
       ShipDate,
       QtyShipped,
       'Open',
       Orders.ReasonNum
  FROM CancelledOrder, Orders, Counter
 WHERE Orders.ReasonNum = CancelledOrder.ReasonNum;

COMMIT;
```

Orders Table for reference

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
   OrderNum      NUMBER (4) PRIMARY KEY,
   OrderDate     DATE,
   CustID        CHAR (3),
   PNum          VARCHAR2 (3),
   UnitPrice     NUMBER,
   QtyOrder      NUMBER,
   TotalCost     NUMBER,
   ShipDate      DATE,
   QtyShipped    NUMBER,
   OrderStatus   VARCHAR2 (10),
   ReasonNum     NUMBER,
   CONSTRAINT fk_CustID FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer (CustID),
   CONSTRAINT fk_PNum FOREIGN KEY (PNum) REFERENCES Product (PNum),
   CONSTRAINT fk_ReasonNum FOREIGN KEY
      (ReasonNum)
       REFERENCES CancelledOrder (ReasonNum)
);
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: you are missing a join condition between orders and counters - something that would not happen if you use "modern" (25 years old) explicit `JOIN` operators instead of the ancient, outdated and fragile implicit joins in the WHERE clause

Comment: Post the CREATE TABLE for CancelledOrders and Counter too

Comment: The Join condition was what I had been missing along with identifying the columns in the manner of tablename.column name. Thank you for the help as my queries now run smoothly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume that `INSERT` should go along with `SELECT`, i.e.

```
insert into ...
select ... from
```

On your example:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (OrderNum,        --> no VALUES keyword, but list of columns
                    OrderDate,
                    CustID,
                    PNum,
                    UnitPrice,
                    QtyOrder,
                    TotalCost,
                    ShipDate,
                    QtyShipped,
                    OrderStatus,
                    reasonnum)        --> reasonnum instead of null
   SELECT MaxNum,
          SYSDATE,
          &vCustID,
          '&vPNum',
          UnitPrice,
          &vQty,
          TotalCost,
          ShipDate,
          QtyShipped,
          'Open',
          Orders.ReasonNum
     FROM CancelledOrder, Orders, Counter
    WHERE Orders.ReasonNum = CancelledOrder.ReasonNum;
```

Also, check `FROM` & `WHERE` clauses: there are 3 tables involved with only one condition. You'll get - as a result - more rows than you expected, unless you fix that (or unless `COUNTER` table contains only 1 row).

Comment: Yes the insert does go along with the select. My Professor said they both go together. The Counter does contain only 1 row. The MaxNum column belongs to it and automatically updates each time an order is made ie: 1001, 1002, 1003. Thanks for the input. I'll try it out.

Comment: Still getting the same error unfortunately. I removed the ReasonNum as a FK on the Orders table and the error has moved to the preceding column and had marked the QtyShipped as an "Invalid Identifier". At this point I just don't know.

Comment: @Sebt1890 Post the structure of your CancelledOrders table too. I have a feeling you may hit problems because some columns in Orders and CancelledOrders are named the same. Always (always) fully qualify your column names as `tablename.columnname` or `tablealias.columnname`, regardless of whether the column name is unique or not; one day it might not be, someone adds a column to some table somewhere and boom, your query stops working. Also, just a quick double check; were any column names created as case sensitive (with " marks?)

Comment: I combined what you said about the tablename.columnname along with the comment above in regards to Joining. It solved it for me. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For these examples, imagine two tables, a and b, with 3 columns each.
When you are inserting, the statement must either use:

**Method A**) Here we instruct the database to INSERT (to all or to specific columns) the results of a query. To do this, we write INSERT INTO   SELECT .....  for example:

```
INSERT INTO table_a select table_b.* from table_b  --Useful when we know how many columns table a and b have;
```

or

```
INSERT INTO table_a select  b.column_2, b.column_3, b.column_1 from table_b --Usefull if b had more columns and we want those three, or if the order of the columns of b needs id different from the order of the columns of a
```

*[In this case, all columns of table a will be filled with the respective columns from the rows of table b that the select part of the query returns]*

or:

```
INSERT INTO table_a (tab_a_column1, tab_a_column3) select b.column_1, b.column_3 from table_b
```

*[In this case, only the specified columns of table a will be filled with the columns from table b that the select part of the query returns]*

*-> Note that in these examples the VALUES keyword is never used*

**Method B**) In this case we instruct the database to insert a sinlge new row with specific values into the table  (to all or to specific columns of the table). In this method we do not use a select query at all:

```
INSERT INTO table_a VALUES ( 1, 'asdf', 5658 ) ;
```

In this example we just give some values to be inserted. They will be put in the corresponding columns of table_a, in the order that the columns are in the table.

```
INSERT INTO table_a (tab_a_column1, tab_a_column3) VALUES (1, 5658);
```

The numbers 1 and 5658 will be inserted to the first and third column, while the second one will be left NULL

So, when using VALUES, we are only inserting one row.
But when using Method A, our one statement may insert any number of rows at one go. It all will depend on how many rows the SELECT part of the query returns.

NOTE: the select part of the query in method A has no limit to how complex it can be. For example it can have multiple joins, where clauses, group by ... and more.

A good link that explains INSERT INTO can be found here:
https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php